# What is the significance of "You forgot your floaties"?

Tags: adventure-time

In the Season 6 Episode 38, Betty has a vision that:

> Simon emerges from the swimming pool as a crab and mouths "You forgot your floaties"

Incidentally, this is the title of the episode. I don't get this reference, what does it mean?

Comment: Oh, *that's* what he said!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Floaties", also known as water wings or, more formally, [Inflatable armbands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflatable_armbands), are just that - inflatable bands worn on the upper arms to assist small children or other people that don't know how to swim. Socially they carry much the same meaning as [training wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training_wheels) on bicycles. Saying "you forgot your floaties" means the same thing as "you forgot your training wheels", i.e. you're stopping relying on outside help, growing up and doing things on your own.

Comment: Ahh, as a non-American, I didn't get the reference. The meaning is clear now. Earlier on Magic Man said that "magic users swim in the loomy gloom". Simon is saying that Betty has fully immersed herself in magic, sadness and madness and is one of them now.

Comment: A reddit comment on this episode also mentioned that maybe she forgot her floaties, so *Betty's in too deep*. Similar idea.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that Betty took a dive off the deep end unprepared and ended up going insane.